# How to install a specific version of webpack globally

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am using web pack to build my react code on a pipeline on server.
However recently there was a major change and now everything is broken.
Here is what I use :

```
npm install -g webpack
```

But I need to install webpack globally like this with version:

```
npm install -g webpack 1.14.0
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try it with webpack@1.14.0 to install a specific version. You likely want to uninstall the other versions first.